# How do i call another view from ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In the `_layout` i have a `button` and i have attached it with `click` event. the `click` event calls an action that will return a complete `view`. what i want to do is load this returning `view` as a new page to the browser. how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.open` to open the new page in a new tab/browser window.

```
$(function(){

  $("#idOfYourLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url=$(this).attr("href");
    window.open(url);
  });

});
```

If it is a button, keep the target url in HTML 5 data attribute.

```
<button id="btn1" data-url="@Url.Action("MyProfile","Home")">Profile</button>
```

In the click event read the data attribute

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        window.open(url);
    });
})
```

If you want to update the same page content via ajax without opening a new tab, you can use jQuery `load()` method to do that. Wrap your `@RenderBody` method call inside a div.

```
<div id="pageContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<button id="btn1" data-url="@Url.Action("MyProfile","Home")">Profile</button>
```

And when the button is clicked, load the new action method's HTML to the pageContent div.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $("#pageContent").load(url);
    });
})
```

Comment: not a new tab, it need to load to the browser just like clicked a link... its like when u click the next button it takes u the next page

Comment: if this is done through ajax would it be over doing?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I updated the answer to use an ajax solution,

Comment: If you have more than one link. Give all of them a css class and bind your click event using the css class selector rather than the Id.